# javascript outer scope question

Tags: javascript, function, scope

It is possible to access ther oute scope of a function?
I will explain better.

I've a function, from which I want to acccess its calling function scope.

```
function called() {
    // i want to access the calling outer function scope
}

function calling() {
    called();
}
```

obviusly `called()` function could be called by a lot of `calling` functions, and `called()` has to know time to time which function has called him,` and access its scope variables and functions.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that? Passing the parameters doesn't fit your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass any relevant information into `called()` as parameters:

```
function called(x, y, z) {
}

function calling() {
   var x = getX();
   var y = computeY();
   var z = retrieveZ();

   called(x, y, z);
}
```

If you expect `called` to do different things, and receive different contextual information, depending on who calls it, you should probably make it multiple separate functions.

Answer (score 5):

No, that isn't possible.

To access a variable from two functions you need to either:

### Declare it in a shared scope

```
var the_variable;
function called() {
    // i want to access the calling outer function scope
}

function calling() {
    called();
}
```

### Pass it as an argument

```
function called(passed_variable) {
    return passed_variable;
}

function calling() {
    var some_variable;
    some_variable = called(some_variable);
}
```

Comment: It's possible, though not part of ES standards, but every browser does support it. See my answer.

Comment: @Mrchief — That lets you find out what the calling function is, it doesn't allow you to access its scope.

Comment: Yes, and I added that in my answer to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

```
function called(outterScope) {
  // outterScope is what you want
  x = outterScope.declaredVariable;
  outterScope.declaredFunction();
}

function calling() {
  this.declaredVariable = 0;
  this.declaredFunction = function() { // do something };

  var _self = this;
  called(_self);
}
```

Comment: This won't catch the lexically scoped variables. Besides, you might as well just use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) if you want to pass the `this` scope to the function

Answer (score 0):

No,

if you need to use variables from scope of calling code block (example function)
you have to pass them in arguments

or you can create object and access properties in Object scope (via `this.param_name`)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you want to do, there might be better ways to do it, but if absoultely have to resort to it, you may find that out via [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller):

```
function myFunc() {
   if (myFunc.caller == null) {
      return ("The function was called from the top!");
   } else
      return ("This function's caller was " + myFunc.caller);
}
```

Do note that its not part of the standards, even though some major browsers and IE7 support it.

Also, you cannot access the caller functions scope or variables. Its usability is limited to finding out who called you (helpful for logging or tracing).

Comment: Not only is this non-standard, it has nothing to do with lexical scope.

Comment: @MAtt: Yes, and you won't get access to variables either. Just to find out the caller function is what this can be used. And I updated my answer too to better reflect the same.